# Text overlapping issue in Textfield in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, textfield

In my textfield there is a right view and datepicker added. When I select the date, text is overlapping with the right view.

[image]

I am using a Designable class for adding right view. How can I fix overlapping issue

Here is the code for setting up rightview

```
rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 17, height: 17))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = rightImage
imageView.tintColor = color
// Added containerView for repositioning image
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 20))
self.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.addSubview(imageView)
rightView = containerView
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code it's kind of hard to tell what is going on here. Do you use storyboards and constraints? Or do you hardcode all the frames of your views?

What I would do here, is using a `UIStackView` and constraints, because it helps getting rid of all the hardcoded positioning values, and it gives you much more flexibility for laying out your UI.

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.placeholder = "16 December 2018"

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [textField, imageView])
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.distribution = .fill
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.spacing = 10

view.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 17).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

As you can see I set the stack view's `distribution` property to `.fill` here, so because the width of your image is constrained to 17, your text field width will adjust to fill the width of the stack view. You may want to adjust this property, and the `spacing` property, depending on what kind of behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: I have used storyboard and setup a designable class where code is added for setting up right view of UITextField. Code for rightview is shared in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with this peace of code:

```
Added Padding For Textfields
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }

 override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
 }

 override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
 }

 override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
 }
```